# In frontend how to get which language is active among installed different languages in Open cart?

Tags: php, e-commerce, opencart

I have installed and themed Opencart 1.5.4x with multiple languages (English, Duch, German) on live server. Opencart application works properly with these languages.

When I click on the language link and browse whole site, the content of the site is translated in this language, **but how to find out, programatically, which language is active?**

I need to show the user which language is currently active.

Comment: See this too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253101/opencart-how-to-make-a-global-variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess You should call `$this->config->get('config_language_id');` within a controller or model to get the ID of currently active language.

That means, if You have implemented Your own language switcher, in Your controller set the language to the template:

```
$this->data['active_language_id'] = $this->config->get('config_language_id');
```

and then within Your template do something like:

```
<?php foreach($languages as $language) { ?>
<a href="..." class="lang-select <?php if $language['language_id'] == $active_language_id) echo ' active'; ?>"><?php echo $language['code']; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

I hope this is what You need to solve and that it would help.

Answer (score 0):

simple language select code in opencart

```
<?php $lang = $this->config->get('config_language');
if($lang == 'ru'){
    $locale = 'ru_RU';
} elseif($lang == 'en'){
    $locale = 'en_US';
} ?>
```

and

```
<?php if ($locale) { echo $locale; } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `$language_code` in your front, it is set by catalog/controller/module/language.php:

```
$this->data['language_code'] = $this->session->data['language'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar question:
I would like to get current selected language at product page,so I can show different "social share code" for different language at product page.

1)go to /catalog/controller/product/product.php
after

```
 $data['heading_title'] = $product_info['name'];
```

add

```
$data['clanguage']  = $this->session->data['language'];
```

go to /catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl

add the following code to where you want it to display.

```
<?php echo $clanguage; ?>
```

now,if you select "English" ,it will show "en-gb",if you select "简体中文"，it will show "zh-cn".

then I can use "if " and "this value" to show different "social share code" for different language.

hope it will help ,
by the it works on opencart 2.3.02,and I think it works on opencart2+,3+.