# Get languages OpenCart

Tags: php, function, opencart

I am trying to get the languages in opencart. In PrestaShop i did it like this:

```
public function getLanguages($active = true, $id_shop = false, $ids_only = false)
{
    $languages = Language::getLanguages($active, $id_shop, $ids_only);

    $langs = "";
    foreach ($languages as $language) {
        $lang = array();
        $lang["lang_id"] = $language['id_lang'];
        $lang["name"] = $language['name'];
        $langs[] = $lang;
    }
    return $langs;
}
```

Is there a similar way to do this in OpenCart?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer [Assign Language Variable in OpenCart](http://sv2109.com/en/article/fastest-way-assign-language-variables-opencart-controller) Or [Loading files in the controller](http://docs.opencart.com/developer/loading/)

```
$this->language->load('path/file');
$this->data['foo1'] = $this->language->get('bar1');
$this->data['foo2'] = $this->language->get('bar2');
```

Hope it help.

Comment: Hello, i am building a web export from our program to opencart and i want to let my program know in which language the shop is from OpenCart. Doe you know which path/file i need to use?

Comment: Hello @StefWinter ! I am not sure what you are asking for but please visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610405/in-frontend-how-to-get-which-language-is-active-among-installed-different-langua .

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$this->language->load('path/file');
$data['first'] = $this->language->get('first');
$data['second'] = $this->language->get('second');
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need all data of the languages. If you need get all languages data   which are installed  you can do like this:

```
$language_data = array();

                $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "language ORDER BY sort_order, name");

                foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
                    $language_data[$result['code']] = array(
                        'language_id' => $result['language_id'],
                        'name'        => $result['name'],
                        'code'        => $result['code'],
                        'locale'      => $result['locale'],
                        'image'       => $result['image'],
                        'directory'   => $result['directory'],
                        'sort_order'  => $result['sort_order'],
                        'status'      => $result['status']
                    );
                }
```

Of course you can create the function with `return  $language_data;`

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty simple:

```
$this->load->model('localisation/language');
$languages = $this->model_localisation_language->getLanguages();
```

Result:

[Xdebug var dump (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lP3Oe.png)